# How to make a private static array in a javascript class?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a static array in a javascript class, for this I do:

```
var Manager = (function () {    
    function Manager() {
      var ubications =  new ArrayList();
      this.ubicationsArray = function () {  
        return(ubication);
      };
    }

    Manager.prototype.addUbication = function (ubication) {
        Manager.ubicationsArray().add(ubication);
    };
    Manager.prototype.getUbication = function (index) {
        return Manager.ubicationsArray().get(index);
    };
    Manager.prototype.sizeOfUbications = function () {
        return Manager.ubicationsArray().size();
    };
    return Manager;
}());
Manager["__class"] = "Manager";
```

Where ubications is the static array and the function ubicationsArray is the public function to acces the array.

I try to use this code with:

```
var ubication = new Ubication(123,456);
var manager = new Manager();
manager.addUbication(ubication);
alert(manager.sizeOfUbications());
```

But I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Manager.ubicationsArray is not a function
```

How is the correct way to use static arrays in a javascript code?

Comment: remove the parens from `ubicationsArray()`; just reference it like ` Manager.ubicationsArray.add(...)`

Comment: @Hamms Manager.ubicationsArray should return the array, shouldn't? But it returns undefined. What could it be?

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't exist in JavaScript, and `Manager["__class"]` doesn't make any sense to me either.

Comment: @AdamLassek I'm using javascript.util https://github.com/bjornharrtell/javascript.util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, JavaScript can only do privacy with respect to function scope.

```
function Manager () {
}

Manager.prototype = (function (){
  var ubications = [];

  return {
    addUbication: function (u) {
      ubications.push(u);
    },

    getUbication: function (index) {
      return ubications[index];
    },

    sizeOfUbications: function () {
      return ubications.length;
    }
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your constructor function, `this.ubicationsArray` assigns a property to the instance of the object, not the constructor itself.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
function Manager() {
}
var ubications =  new ArrayList();
Manager.ubicationsArray = function () {
  return(ubication);
};
```

Note that this property isn't really "private". This would be more-private:

```
var Manager = (function () {    
    function Manager() {
    }

    var ubications =  new ArrayList();

    Manager.prototype.addUbication = function (ubication) {
        ubications.add(ubication);
    };
    Manager.prototype.getUbication = function (index) {
        return ubications.get(index);
    };
    Manager.prototype.sizeOfUbications = function () {
        return ubications.size();
    };
    return Manager;
}());
Manager["__class"] = "Manager";
```